# OSError: Function not implemented - Odoo Docker - command: ["odoo","--dev","xml,reload"]

Tags: docker, docker-compose, odoo, odoo-12, docker-command

```yaml
version: '3.4'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/db-files/
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  odoo:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8069:8069"
    volumes:
      - ./extra-addons:/mnt/custom-addons
      - ./data/odoo:/var/lib/odoo
    command: ["odoo","--dev","xml,reload"]
```

This is my docker-compose.yml file

When I use Ubuntu, it works. But when I use MacOS, it doesn't work. The problem is command: ["odoo","--dev","xml,reload"]. When I comment it, I can run on MacOS
Please help me fix it

Comment: Probably it's not implemented on Mac?

Comment: Are you just trying to run a prepackaged application, or is this something you're actually developing?  Can you [edit] the question to include the complete exception and the associated source code?